# What is the Execution Flow in E-BIZ Concurrent Program XML files?

Tags: xml, oracle

As part of my project I wrote an XML report which extract rows from a Oracle SQL statement and then give the rows in XML format as output.(When executed through E-BIZ Concurrent Program).

Here I attached the Structure of my XML and I need to understand the flow of it to debug the errors receiving.

i cannot share the exact XML has it would be organisations compliance issue. So sharing a similar snippet. 
I want to know how the execution works.How the execution pointer moves.
For eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataTemplate version="1.0" description="XXX_XXX_XXX" 
        name="XXX_XXX_XXX">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="P_START_DATE" dataType = "DATE"> </parameter>
            <parameter name="P_END_DATE" dataType = "DATE"> </parameter>
            <parameter name="P_DEPARTMENT" dataType = "NUMBER"> </parameter>
        </parameters>
     <lexicals> </lexicals>
     <dataQuery>
        <sqlStatement name="Q_1">
            <![CDATA[
                SELECT *  FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DATE_OF_JOINING BETWEEN 
                :P_START_DATE AND :P_END_DATE AND DEPARTMENT = :P_DEPARTMENT
            ]]>

        </sqlStatement>
     </dataQuery>
     <dataStructure>
            <group name="G_1" dataType="varchar2" source="Q_1">
                                <element name="SUPERVISOR_NAME" dataType="VARCHAR2" value="SUPERVISOR_NAME"/>
                                <element name="EMPLOYEE_NAME" dataType="VARCHAR2" value="EMPLOYEE_NAME"/>
                                <element name="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" dataType="NUMBER" value="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER"/>
                                <element name="DEPARTMENT" dataType="VARCHAR2" value="DEPARTMENT"/>
                                <element name="EMPLOYEE_EMAIL" dataType="VARCHAR2" value="EMPLOYEE_EMAIL"/>
                                <element name="SALARY" dataType="NUMBER" value="SALARY"/>
                </group>
     </dataStructure>
    </dataTemplate>
```

Will the Sql statements execute first and then the data structure display one row picking from the fetched rows OR Will they run in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share what XML structure you want as your output.

### Also share queries you are using .

Based on your input, First the query is executed and data structure is applied on that projection. TBH, I am not still able to get your question completely.

During the XML file generation,if there is an issue with data , XML file shows partially rendered.

Comment: I Added it to the description